# I have projects in the Bluemix Globalization service. Is there a way to transfer to the Globalization Pipeline?

Tags: ibm-cloud, globalization-pipeline

I'm using  the `ibm-globalization` service on Bluemix. Is there a way to transfer them to the Globalization Pipeline service besides re-uploading them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't made any edits to the key value pairs, you can simply upload your resource file and the service will re-translate your strings. As the beta service is free of charge, there is no cost to you.